# AppInventor - Getting user review in Play Store from created app?

Tags: android, app-inventor

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the user of an app created in AppInventor to review/rate the app in the Play Store?

I mean like, is there a way to use something like the Activity Starter to link directly to the Google Play Store "Write A Review" option?

Answer (score 0):

[How to launch Google Play from within your app](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2play)

[image]